# Class 'phpseclib\Crypt\Random' not found

Tags: php, phpseclib, jwe

I want to do JWE in php. I've installed gree/jose library and also phpseclib via composer. But, why I'm keep getting error below?

> Fatal error: Class 'phpseclib\Crypt\Random' not found in
> /export/vhost/onlinepayment.com.my/htdocs/NBepay/vendor/gree/jose/src/JOSE/JWE.php
> on line 106

below are the libraries that i've installed.

1. composer require gree/jose
2. composer require phpseclib/phpseclib:~3.0

Already included autoload and the JOSE.

```
include_once $FIXPATH."vendor/autoload.php";
use \JOSE\JWE;
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

gree/jose requires `phpseclib/phpseclib:~2.0` - not 3.0. If you want to use 3.0 and 2.0 side by side you'll need to require `phpseclib/phpseclib2_compat:~1.0` in addition to `phpseclib/phpseclib:~3.0`.

This is relevant because phpseclib v3 has a new namespace - phpseclib3\Crypt\Random instead of phpseclib\Crypt\Random. The name space change is what makes `phpseclib/phpseclib2_compat:~1.0` possible